# How to prevent linebreaks in chapter title?

Tags: line-breaking, chapters

I have the following chapter title:
[image]

with the following code:
`\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{\chaptername}{-2pt}{\Huge \bfseries} \titlespacing{\chapter}{186pt}{-120pt}{27pt}`

I want to prevent this  linebreak, that the line continues forever.  I have already tried minipages and  nolinebreak, all of that does not work? Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: you haven't provided a test file (or said how you have defined `\titleformat` which isn't a standard command) so this is untested but I would guess replacing `\Huge \bfseries` by `\Huge \bfseries\mbox` would work.

Comment: you're a legend! you made my day! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `\Huge \bfseries` by `\Huge \bfseries\mbox` would work as the last command in that slot may be a command that takes an argument (intended for `\MakeUppercase` really)